# Easiest way to combine the current from 2-3 USB-C PD ports

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated

I'm working on a project that has about a ~100W power requirement (5v, on average 20A, which needs to run for 10 hours off of the battery); and which needs to be portable and lightweight.

I'm currently powering it with 3 Anker - PowerCore III Elite 25600 mah power banks; I have 3 USB-C 20v PD triggers that are plugged into the 65W port of each of the power banks with 3 USB-C cables. I usually put the power banks in a backpack and run 3 USB-C cables from the power banks to the system. These 3 are essentially 3 separate power supplies each with its own 20v-5v buck converter and I've been running a third of the project off of each. This technically works and runs for the full time we need, but it's pretty messy having so many cables and pretty annoying since it easily results in a glitched state if the wrong component gets power before another.

I would like to rebuild this to be a single power supply, powered by a single cable that carries all 100W (or more). So I am wondering if there is an easy way to connect the 3 65W USB-C ports on the power banks together to have a single 100W or higher output USB-C PD port (and then I could just use a single cable connected to a single USB-C PD trigger). I haven't been able to find a single battery pack which outputs 100W *and* is lightweight enough to be practical. I am pulling 20v 3a from each battery pack; it would be nice if I could just connect them in parallel to add up the current, and I considered doing that with the DC outputs on the USB-C triggers, but was told that it wouldn't work because the voltages would not be exactly equal. I have considered RC batteries, which turned out to be far too heavy (nearly double the weight for the same capacity?). I have also considered trying to build my own battery pack from 18650 cells, and was talked out of doing that on safety concerns. USB-C here isn't a hard requirement so I am also open to other suggestions if there is another easier way to do it.